# Where does Powershell DSC find the module code?

Tags: powershell, puppet, dsc

I found an error in the Archive DSC module (MSFT_ArchiveResource.psm1). After copying the code, debugging it in the ISE and figuring out the two lines that needed to be fixed, I want to make the change to the real file and test using Puppet and the msutter/dsc module, which makes use of the Archive Resource.

I found where I thought was the location of the file on my machine:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\PSDesiredStateConfiguration\DSCResources\MSFT_ArchiveResource\MSFT_ArchiveResource.psm1
```

However, when I run Puppet, it is clear that my changed code is not being exercised. (If I set $Debug = $true at the top of the file, I do not see the extra output.) Is there some Windows cache that holds this file that I must clear? Is it being loaded from a ZIP or other archive?

I doubt that Puppet is related to the issue, but mention it in case it rings a bell. (I only made the code change on the Agent.)

**UPDATE:**

When I run the following line in Powershell, I do not find any process with the expected name containing "dsccore":

```
Get-WmiObject msft_providers | select -ExpandProperty provider
```

Results:

```
RegistryEventProvider
PolicyAgentInstanceProvider
CIMWin32
Msft_ProviderSubSystem
SCM Event Provider
Win32_WIN32_TERMINALSERVICE_Prov
WmiPerfClass
WmiPerfClass
WmiPerfInst
WmiPerfInst
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Troubleshooting DSC](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn249926.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

> ### My resources won’t update: How to reset the cache
>
> The DSC engine caches resources implemented as a PowerShell module for efficiency
>   purposes. However, this can cause problems when you are authoring a
>   resource and testing it simultaneously because DSC will load the
>   cached version until the process is restarted. The only way to make
>   DSC load the newer version is to explicitly kill the process hosting
>   the DSC engine.
>
> To identify which process is hosting the DSC engine and stop it on a
>   per instance basis, you can list the process ID of the WmiPrvSE which
>   is hosting the DSC engine. Then, to update the provider, stop the
>   WmiPrvSE process using the commands below, and then run
>   Start-DscConfiguration again.

```powershell
###
### find the process that is hosting the DSC engine
###
$dscProcessID = Get-WmiObject msft_providers | 
Where-Object {$_.provider -like 'dsccore'} | 
Select-Object -ExpandProperty HostProcessIdentifier 

###
### Stop the process
###
Get-Process -Id $dscProcessID | Stop-Process
```

Comment: The advice you give I found on this page: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn249926.aspx

Comment: Yes, I linked it already (click the Troubleshooting DSC header in my answer), and that's why I used the quote tags.

Comment: When I execute the first line, I get no process Id returned. I do see many WmiPrvSE.exe processes in Task Manager, but do not know which is for DSC.

Comment: The only thing that worked was rebooting the computer. I was hoping to find a solution that executes fast and does not require a reboot.

Answer (score 0):

In WMF 5.0 DSC added the option to force import the modules without killing the process.  It is documented on [MSDN here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/PowerShell/DSC/metaConfig).

Here is an example of how to enable it:

```ps1
configuration settings
{
    LocalConfigurationManager
    {
        DebugMode = 'ForceModuleImport'
    }
}

$outputPath = "$env:temp\lcmSettings"

settings -outputPath $outputPath
Set-DscLocalConfigurationManager -Path $outputPath -Force -Verbose
```